# error using \foreach with ellipse directions

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

The following line

```
\foreach \x / \y in {0.422201/1.000000,1.000000/2.368540}
  {\draw[very thin] (0,0) ellipse (\x and \y)};
```

gives

```
ERROR: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `a' or `an' (in '0.422201and 1.000000').
```

Then I tried `(\x{} and \y)` as it looked like a space problem, but that
doesn't work either.

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@ 

l.10 ...aw[very thin] (0,0) ellipse (\x{} and \y)}
```

Here's the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (4,4);
    \begin{scope}[rotate=12.549]
      \foreach \x / \y in {0.422201/1.000000,1.000000/2.368540}
        {\draw[very thin] (0,0) ellipse (\x and \y)};
      % \draw[very thin] (0,0) ellipse (0.422201 and 1.000000);
      % \draw[very thin] (0,0) ellipse (1.000000 and 2.368540);
      \draw[very thin] (0,0) ellipse (1.349721 and 3.196868);
      \draw[very thin] (0,0) ellipse (1.625882 and 3.850967);
      \draw[very thin] (0,0) ellipse (1.861515 and 4.409073);
      \draw[very thin] (0,0) ellipse (2.070504 and 4.904071);
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and the intended result

[image: concentric ellipses]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enclose the `\x` and `\y` (better be safe) inside braces for the space after `\x` is swallowed making it `0.422201and`. Further, you have to put `;` inside the closing brace in

```
  {\draw[very thin] (0,0) ellipse ({\x} and {\y});}
```

With these,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (4,4);
    \begin{scope}[rotate=12.549]
      \foreach \x / \y in {0.422201/1,1/2.368540,1.349721/3.196868,1.625882/3.850967,1.861515/4.409073,2.070504/4.904071}
        {\draw[very thin] (0,0) ellipse ({\x} and {\y});
        }      
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use the alternative syntax for ellipses which is:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (4,4);
        \begin{scope}[rotate=12.549]
            \foreach \x/\y in {0.422201/1.000000,1.000000/2.368540,1.349721/3.196868,1.625882/3.850967,1.861515/4.409073,2.070504/4.904071}
            \draw[very thin] (0,0) ellipse [x radius=\x,y radius=\y];
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```